# remove unknown advertise from website

Tags: php, .htaccess, ads

I need help to remove some advertise which comes under a few my client's machines. It's comes as big banner advertise in the  free area of index page and each advertise has a message as "ads by sense" .

I can not inform any user to uninstall the useless browser plugins as this advertise never appear in other site like google.com,yahoo.com or boston.com etc at same machine. OR may be they are not TECHNICALLY GOOD in remove BROWSER add-ons.

Please help me how can I remove this useless advertise from my site without program in PHP or .HTACCESS file or ther Technics

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can control web page behaviour once its on clients browser, I mean, the browser queries for ads and places on your page. Those ads are not loaded from your website side.

Comment: Why it's not coming in other site like google.com,gmail.com

Comment: You mean advertising networks? Well, those adv depends upon malware extensions they're using on their browser. So the admin of that extension will decide which ads to show :)

Comment: Okay.How to remove this malware extensions from site

Comment: I already told you. Those malware extensions are on your client side & probably on your pc too as you can see those ads. They are not on site .

Comment: I  don't know.but some thing must be their to solve this....